# How to validate a number against a list in Bash?

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I have a list of numbers like this:

```
limit=( '1' '2' '3' '4' '5' '6' '7' '8' '9' )
```

Then I want to check the input value to see if it exists in the list. For example:

```
echo 'Type a number from 1 to 9'
read input
if [ "$input" = "limit" ]
then
exit
else
echo 'Wrong number'
```

Something like that. If I put limit=9 and use [ "$input" -le "$limit" ] it'll accept numbers like 0, -1, and I don't want that.

Comment: I don't know what you mean. What do you want it to accept? Do you mean you want to compare input to every element in the array? You would need to use a loop or possible write the limits as regex and then use `=~`

Comment: Yes I want to compare input to every element in the array, but also want to know how to put more than one element in it. How do I that loop? And I didn't really understood the other method. I tried to this: `if [[ $input =~ [1-31] ]]` but every number and letters with numbers works.

Comment: I want it to accept only numbers from 01 to 31.

Comment: I don't get what's wrong with "Please help." '.'